# Strange Issue for Sawing and hiding the Navigation bar

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

I have an application which presents few screens using navigation controller,  On my First screen i have hide the navigation bar , When i Push On the Second screen I set my Navigation bar visable  and When i pop from the Second screen to first screen i saw the one black stripe on the first screen, Can you please give me the Solution of this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to hide navigationBar when second screen pop means in viewWillDisappear method of second screen.

Comment: Yaa I had try in second screen viewWillDisappear but its display the one moving black stripe ,

Answer (score 1):

Please hide your navigation bar in `ViewWillAppear` and not on `ViewDidLoad`, because while poping from second view `viewWillAppear` will be called first